# How do I properly word this question in French?

Tags: adjectifs, ordre-des-mots, questions, interrogative

I would like to say what is your favorite song of his. Do I say "Quelle est ta chanson de lui préférée?" or would I say "De ses chansons, quelle est ton préférée?" or are both of these constructions wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To correct your proposals:

- *Quelle est ta chanson préférée de lui ?*
- *De ses chansons, quelle est ta préférée ?* (*chanson* is a feminine noun).

Or other suggestions:

- *Laquelle de ses chansons préfères-tu ?*
- *Laquelle de ses chansons tu préfères ?* (oral context)
- *Quelle est sa chanson que tu préfères ?*
- *Laquelle de ses chansons est ta préférée ?*
- *C'est quoi ta chanson préférée de lui ?* (same as your first proposal but more informal, for oral context)

Comment: Adding on to your list- "Laquelle de ses chansons est ta préférée?"